# What is this elongated plastic and metal utensil?

Tags: utensils

I inherited this utensil as part of a larger cutlery case containing lots of other stuff, all related to the kitchen somehow.
I do not know what this is supposed to be for, it might even be part of something else.
There is what seems to be a hole for a screw, and a long elongated plastic thing squishes between the metal frame.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: It could be part of a [mess kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mess_kit).

Comment: @Karlo I concur - it definitely looks like part of a camping cookware set - removable so that you can leave the pot over an open campfire without risk of melting the handle.  You should make a full answer out of that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's a handle that has become unbolted from the pot it was attached to. For example, with that angle it would fit a wok. It may even be intentionally removable.

Comment: It's all so obvious now. Thanks, I just didn't make the connection :).

Comment: How would that work? If you'd bolt this to a wok, the handle would be pointing inwards?

Comment: No, the bolt is on the outside.

Comment: @FuzzyChef exactly. The bolt is on the outside, but since there is a clip in the way, you can only stick the bolt in through the other side. That would mean the handle would be pointing inwards of the pan.

Comment: @Opifex https://pasteboard.co/kPR0LpozikeB.png

Comment: that's a weird construction. the low bolt hole means a large lever at the top, that ca never be stable. also, why the hook below the hole?

Comment: @ths: There are two places of resistance: A mounting hole/peg attachment and a rectangular plate..  Jonatan's diagram focuses on the mounting hole/peg, which blocks vertical force and keeps the handle from detaching.  However, OP's images show a flange that likely fits against a very narrow rectangular plate.  Mind you, even if there isn't a metal plate, friction between the metal will be enough to prevent most accidental rotation.

Comment: It really comes down to: is that small fold of metal a flat plate or a hook?  We can't see in the pictures provided.  We'd need a 90deg side view.

Comment: @JonatanCloutier Your link doesn't work for me. In any case, I don't see how this can be mounted to a pan in a sensible manner. See my answer for the reason of my scepticism.

Answer (score 21):

To me it looks like this is a grill pan handle.

These are used to lift the (potentially hot) grill pan under the grill. Many are detachable so that the handle doesn't get hot.

There are other that are non-detachable but held in place with a screw. Often people just remove these so that they are easier to store. I suspect you have one of these.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think the other answers are correct. The hook at the bottom would not allow the handle to be bolted to a pan.

It looks more like a detachable handle for a [deep fryer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_fryer). The ones I'm familiar with all have a handle that can easily be detached from the basket so it allows for easy storage. (you can drop the handle in the basket and close the lid)

Comment: It doesn't look like a hook to me in the photos ... we need a side elevation to be sure.

Comment: Yeah I can see this being a deep fryer handle.

Answer (score 4):

It can be part of a [mess kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mess_kit), as removable handle of a skillet or food tray.

As mentioned by Darrel Hoffman, you can remove the handle while the pot is over an open campfire.

Answer (score 1):

It is a detachable handle for the basket of a steamer or deep fryer, or possibly a casserole pan. My stove came with something similar for lifting the broiler pan out from under the griddle. If you also inherited a vintage stove or special type of cooker, do a search for accessories specific to that appliance.